# How can I check if homebrew-core is a shallow clone in a bash script?

Tags: bash, git, homebrew

How can I check, in a bash script, if currently `homebrew-core` and `homebrew-cask` are shallow clones and unshallow them if they are? If they are already not shallow, I would like to print a message as well.

Running `git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask" fetch --unshallow` on an already non shallow clone just gives an error message instead of graceful handling.

I tried this

```
if [[ "git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" == "false" ]] 
then
    echo "homebrew core is already non shallow. Moving to next step."
else
    git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
fi
```

but got

```
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense
```

Comment: “instead of graceful handling” Then add graceful handling to the script?

Comment: @matt: that's what he's trying to do. I'm not sure why this is downvoted (there might be a duplicate, but if so, that should just call for a close-as-duplicate).

Comment: @torek Yeah, no idea what's going on with the voting on this one (the OP even gives an answer and _that_ was downvoted).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seemed to work

```
if [[ "git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core | grep -q 'false'" ]] 
then
    echo "homebrew core is already non shallow. Moving to next step."
else
    git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
$ for d in homebrew-core homebrew-cask
do
    (cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/$d && git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository)
done
```

it will print `true` or `false` if the repo is shallow.